# Can you deactivate the FlowApplication Error email messages when process builder has an issue

Tags: process-builder

I built a process that is only supposed to happen when a field is not null. When it is null, an email message is sent from FlowApplication - "The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.nihrm__Inquiry__r.NI_Market_Segment__c because it hasn't been set or assigned."
Is there a way to prevent the email from being sent to the system admin? I have another process that fills out the region on an account based on state/country and the org has the salesforce account dupe catching feature enabled. When they save an account that fires the dupe logic, an email is sent about the flow.